# Set margin equivalent to transform scale

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to scale the active `li` from an `ul` to 1.5 `transform: scale(1.5);`. How can I set the margin dynamically considering `scale()`'s value?

I have a sass compiler and the value of `scale()` is set with a variable. How can I add a margin equivalent to `scale()`'s value?

(In e.g. if 1.5 scales 2px, I would like to achieve `margin: 0 2px;`)

**EDIT**

Here is my code:

```css
/* 
    $paginator value is 1.25
    margin: 0 ?px; is what I am asking for
*/
&.active {
    margin: 0 ?px;
    transform: scale($paginator);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: @Arkellys I just edited my question to add the code

Comment: @Robgher what is the starting value for the margin you want?

Comment: scale is based on the width/height of the element so you need this information to set the margin

Comment: @TemaniAfif I do not know if this is what you asked, but ```li```'s initial size is 32x34 px

Comment: @SamWillis The px that ```scale``` adds to the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul>
  <li>list 1</li>  
  <li class='active'>list 1</li>
  <li>list 1</li>
</ul>
```

SASS:

```
@mixin scale( $scale: 1.5, $margin: 2) {
   margin: 0 $scale * $margin * 1px;
   transform: scale($scale);
}

li {
  color: red;
    padding: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;

}

li.active {
  @include scale(1.5, 20); //arguments are optional

}
```

Comment: The mixin is not required.

Comment: @Arkellys No, but it helps with keeping the code cleaner and makes sure the calculations are based on the correct variable values.

Comment: Works as expected! Thank you
PS: In my case I used @include scale(1.25, 4);